# How to install a list of programs in a .txt file automatically through a terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation, text-processing

I'm sure I've seen instructions on how do do this unfortunately it was a few months ago and have forgotten them.

Thanks in advance to anyone who answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
xargs -rxa files_to_install.txt -- sudo apt-get install --
```

will work.

Comment: I would suggest `$(< files_to_install.txt)`

Comment: @enzotib Out of curiosity, why is that better?

Comment: @WarriorIng64: it is all done with bash, without using external process. It snould be a little bit more efficient

Comment: Thx for your answer. on a ubuntu 14.04, I get the folloing error: `Argument list too long`. Any ideas, why?

Comment: @toesslab.ch: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work when the file contains any program which is not recognized by the system. But better if skip this program and continue installation of other programs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Synaptic Package Manager, in your text file, you structure it in the following format:

where package name e.g. gimp
 would be a space or tabs
 can be install, remove, purge

And obviously put each package on a new line. No need to include dependencies.

Then in Synaptic, go to File > Read Markings and point it to your file. What this does is mark all the changes to be made and then you can proceed as usual. I have not tried @Jo-erlend's method but it definitely sounds simpler